# Toggle any tag just like execCommand bold does with b

Tags: javascript, html

I have contenteditable div and need to be able to wrap/unwrap text into other tags like `<code>` and so on.
Wrapping them isn't problem, rather unwrapping selected text is, like when there is `<b>hello </b><code>world</code>` and I need to unwrap only letters in middle (orl), there doesn't seem to be simple way detect if selected text is inside `<code>` tag or no. So while `document.execCommand("bold")` does this wrapping/unwrapping job perfectly with `<b>` and `<i>` tags, is there any way to do same with other tags except b, i, u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after longer time searching for solution and finding nothing, I decided to try to write it on my own, so if anyone finds this piece useful I will be glad.
I don't know how it performs on IE or Safari and for sure it's not the most efficient way how to do it, but for most of browsers it should do the job.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wrap</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function traverseParentCE(el){
                var parent = el.parentElement;
                if(!parent || (el && el.contentEditable=="true")) return el;
                while(parent && parent.contentEditable!="true"){
                    parent = parent.parentElement;
                }
                return parent;
            }
            function finishWrap(el, innHtml, marker, wrapper){
                el.innerHTML = innHtml.replace("<"+marker+">","").replace("</"+marker+">","");
                var node = el.getElementsByTagName(wrapper)[0];
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.setStart(node, 0);
                range.setEnd(node, 1);
                var sel = document.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
            function wrap(tag){
                var marker = "marker";
                var wrapper = "inncnt";
                var ae = document.activeElement;
                if(ae.contentEditable!="true") return;
                var sel = document.getSelection();
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                var el = document.createElement(marker);
                el.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
                range.deleteContents();
                range.insertNode(el);
                var innHtml = el.innerHTML;
                var count = 0;
                while(true){    // I know right, this kind of replacing is horrible, but RegExp somehow didn't work for me
                    var pos = innHtml.indexOf("<"+tag+">");
                    if(pos==-1) break;
                    innHtml = innHtml.replace("<"+tag+">","").replace("</"+tag+">","");
                    count++;
                }
                innHtml.replace("<"+wrapper+">","").replace("</"+wrapper+">","");
                el.innerHTML = "<"+wrapper+">" + innHtml + "</"+wrapper+">";
                var container = traverseParentCE(range.commonAncestorContainer);
                innHtml = container.innerHTML;
                if(count>0){
                    return finishWrap(container, innHtml, marker, wrapper);
                }
                var pos = innHtml.indexOf("<"+marker+">");
                var contentBefore = innHtml.substr(0, pos);
                var lastStarting = contentBefore.indexOf("<"+tag+">");
                var lastEnding = contentBefore.indexOf("</"+tag+">");
                var wrap = false;
                if(lastStarting == -1) wrap = true;
                else if(lastStarting < lastEnding) wrap = true;
                if(wrap) innHtml = innHtml.replace(marker, tag).replace(marker, tag);
                else innHtml = innHtml.replace(marker, "/"+tag).replace("/"+marker,tag);
                var doublet = "<"+tag+"></"+tag+">";
                while(true){
                    var pos = innHtml.indexOf(doublet);
                    if(pos==-1) break;
                    innHtml = innHtml.replace(doublet, "");
                }
                return finishWrap(container, innHtml, marker, wrapper);
            }
        </script>
        <button onmousedown="wrap('b'); return false;" onmouseup="return false;" onclick="return false;">B</button>
        <button onmousedown="wrap('i'); return false;" onmouseup="return false;" onclick="return false;">I</button>
        <button onmousedown="wrap('code'); return false;" onmouseup="return false;" onclick="return false;">Code</button>
        <div style="width: 800px; height: 300px; background-color: yellow" contenteditable="true" id="out">
            Hello <b>World</b>! This <code>is some</code> sentence.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather surprising that execCommand() didn't have this capability natively. Uh, long live execCommand()!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying contenteditable divs is no simple task. What you ask is possible, but far too large a topic and isn't answerable with a few examples here.

However there are many ready-made libraries that have done this before (for example [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). They are very complex, but also very flexable. Out of the box, they probably do much more than you need, but they can be configured so that features you don't need can be disabled, and they have an API allowing you to control them from the outside, if needed.